# How to change Angular bind value when using observable object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to convert the offset value for time object in the URI, and the object is in observable object.

The error that I'm facing is:

```
ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '2023-11-20T00:00:00-05:00'. Current value: '2023-11-20T00:00:00-06:00'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
```

HTML code:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let app of siteGroup[site.name]">
                          <ng-template #tipContent1>
                            <div class="tooltip-container">
                              {{site.name}} - {{app.description}}
                            </div>
                          </ng-template>
                          <a class="clickable" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent1" [openDelay]="200" container="body"
                            ngbDropdownItem routerLink="/site/{{site.name}}/{{app.name}}"
                            [queryParams]="{caseName: routeParams.caseName, windowSize:  routeParams.windowSize, startTime: changeCurrentParamTimezoneStartTime() , endTime: changeCurrentParamTimezoneEndtime(), equipmentTypes: routeParams.equipmentTypes}"
                            (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)">
                            {{app.name}}
                          </a>
                        </ng-container>
```

The function to change if the time object exist in

```
 changeCurrentParamTimezoneStartTime(){
    //initial value could be 2023-11-20T00:00:00-05:00
    if(this.routeParams.startTime){
      this.routeParams.startTime = this.routeParams.startTime.slice(0,10);

      this.routeParams.startTime = moment(this.routeParams.startTime)
                                  .utcOffset(parseFloat(this.timeZoneOffset), true)
                                  .startOf('day')
                                  .format();    

      //and the return value i want is 2023-11-20T00:00:00-06:00
      return this.routeParams.startTime;  
    }
    else{
          return;
    }
    
   
  }

  changeCurrentParamTimezoneEndtime(){
    // return null
    if( this.routeParams.endTime){

      this.routeParams.endTime = this.routeParams.endTime.slice(0,10);

      this.routeParams.endTime = this.routeParams.endTime = moment(this.routeParams.endTime)
                                .utcOffset(parseFloat(this.timeZoneOffset), true)
                                .endOf('day')
                                .format();      
      return this.routeParams.endTime;         
    }
    else{
      return;
    }
    
  }
```

and the observable object are initiallized in ngoninit

```
 this.navigationService.routeParams.subscribe(routeParams => this.routeParams = routeParams);
```

When I console the value, I can see the value is updated but the URI hasn't changed for the offset value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error states that there is a change in the component's data after the change detection has already run for the current cycle. Angular performs change detection to make sure that the component's data is consistent and doesn't change unexpectedly during a single cycle. If it detects changes after it has checked the component, it throws this error.

In your case to resolve try adding the below at the end of the ngOnInit

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {} // Dependency inject here

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.navigationService.routeParams.subscribe(routeParams => { 
       this.routeParams = routeParams
       this.cdr.detectChanges(); // Manually trigger change detection
    });
         
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); // Manually trigger change detection
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, this actually works for me thanks!

Comment: Happy to help appreciate if you can provide an upvote to the answer too.